# XGBoost multi:softmax objective function

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I have a question regarding the `multi:softmax` objective function in relation to XGBoost. I've been playing around with the objective function a bit in the context of a multi-class classification and I've noticed something I don't quite understand.

Suppose we have a multi class classification problem with three different classes. So I want to use `multi:softmax` as objective and set `num_class = 3` as recommended in the documentation of XGBoost. Everything works as expected.

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html

Now I set `num_class = 2` for the same problem setting and XGBoost still works as before.

Why does it still work even though `num_class` was set incorrectly?